# Custom domain for slot in an azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a working azure web app, and ran into some issues while creating a new slot for it, the custom domain that is set for the web app follows the pattern:

*appname-projectname-webapp-win-ne.azurewebsites.net*

But when I created a slot the custom domain for it was created as:

*appname-projectname-webapp-win--slotname.azurewebsites.net*

Missing the **ne** on the domain, so my questions are:

1. Is there any known reason to why that part would be removed?
2. Is there a way to change the domain for the slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being truncated to fit in the allowable length of Azure Web app names (**2-59**  alphanumerics and hyphens).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftweb for details.